# Porting from Jetty 11 to Jetty 12. Missing RequestLogHandler

Tags: jetty

I am porting application that uses Jetty as a HTTP server from Jetty 11 to Jetty 12.

I have problem with `RequestLogHandler` class, which seems to be missing in Jetty 12.

```java
var address = new InetSocketAddress(settings.getBindingInterface(), settings.getPort());
var jettyServer = new Server(address);
var handler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.NO_SESSIONS);
handler.setContextPath("/");

var statisticsHandler = new StatisticsHandler();
statisticsHandler.setHandler(handler);

var requestLogHandler = new RequestLogHandler();
requestLogHandler.setHandler(statisticsHandler);

var requestLog = new CustomRequestLog(new Slf4jRequestLogWriter(), CustomRequestLog.NCSA_FORMAT);
requestLogHandler.setRequestLog(requestLog);
handler.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler());
jettyServer.setHandler(requestLogHandler);
```

Can you help me to:

- confirm that `RequestLogHandler` is now gone (and not moved to a separate artifact)
- optionally, find the pull request that introduced that change
- write equivalent code in Jetty 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Server.setRequestLog(RequestLog)` instead.

The `RequestLogHandler` was an artifact from the Jetty 5 thru Jetty 9 era.

It was heavily neutered in Jetty 10, and does almost nothing compared to Jetty 9.

The use of `Server.setRequestLog(RequestLog)` is even mentioned in the javadoc for `RequestLogHandler` in Jetty 10/11.

The server level version logs all requests, even failures, errors, bad requests, request that don't have a path, request that don't match a context, etc...